# Several heaps in virtual memory

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

Is there a way to have two heaps (or more) in the virtual memory space? I use `brk()` function to move the break point of the bottom heap. But I would like to have another heap somewhere with another break point and a function to allocate/deallocate space.

That way the bottom heap is controlled by `malloc()`. The other heap is controlled by my own memory-management function. This way I would like to improve the performance of my application.

Comment: Most operating systems have a way to allocate and manage memory with functions like `mmap()/mremap()/munmap()/` and the like. You may allocate additional heaps of memory with these and manage the usage yourself.

Comment: @LPs: how do you think `operator new` is implemented in common compilers? C++ was created as an OO extension above C and still relies on C standard library. Normal programmers should not use it, but the C++ standard library generally uses `malloc`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I meant: use `malloc` using [tag:c++]  code is non sense.